Ansible writing value to a file from different host while running in different host
i'm writing a script to fetch FQDN for different hosts.
i want to write a script in ansible where i can fetch FQDN's of app and web server and store it in a file in app server. is this madeable?
- name: Get FQDN for host
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Get FQDN for host
      win_shell: |
        $fqdn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).HostName
        Write-Host "$fqdn"
      register: fqdn_output

    - name: Set appfqdn as a variable if in 'app' group
      set_fact:
        appfqdn: "{{ fqdn_output.stdout }}"
      when: '"app" in group_names'

    - name: Set webfqdn as a variable if in 'web' group
      set_fact:
        webfqdn: "{{ fqdn_output.stdout }}"
      when: '"web" in group_names'

- name: Deploy configuration file on app servers
  hosts: app
  tasks:
    - name: Set FQDNs in a config file on app server
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: DiscoveryPeerList.config.j2
        dest: "C:/Program Files (x86)/ABC/test.config"

- name: Update config file with webfqdn on app servers
  hosts: app
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure webfqdn is in the config file if in 'web' group
      win_lineinfile:
        path: "C:/Program Files (x86)/ABC/test.config"
        line: "webfqdn={{ webfqdn }}"
        state: present
      when: '"web" in group_names'

i tried above set of code but i'm getting ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, tasks
